# weighting for non-response in a census-like survey

Tags: survey

I am analysing survey results for a large organization. I have a frame of 8000 people with demographic information. Apparently, around 6000 of these people had valid e-mail addresses, and the survey was sent to all 6,000 (I'm rounding the numbers here, but this is the gist of it). Around 1500 replied.

I want to post-stratify on the frame variables to adjust for potential non-response bias. Should I reweight back to the original population, or should I reweight back to the population of persons with e-mails?

Note: it doesn't seem to have much impact on the estimates either way, since valid e-mail appears to be fairly random.

Further note: there are political reasons why we need to be able to stand behind the numbers we publish.